# is Subsonic 3 compatible with the latest release of Mono?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

The latest stable release of Mono right now is 2.4.2.3.  Does subsonic 3 work with it? I know Mono isn't compatible with all .net 3.5 features yet, but I'm presuming compatibility depends on which specific language features of .net 3.5 Subsonic uses.  Does anyone know for a fact whether it's compatible?

Answer (score 1):

Its compatible - just remember to use an actual version of MySQL connector, if planning to use MySQL.
And there is an Error in current SubSonic (see [Issue 111](http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/issues/detail?id=111#c1)). Change IsDbNull to IsDBNull in *SubSonic.Core/Linq/Structure/ExecutionBuilder.cs* and recompile.

That did it for me with Mono 2.6 and MySQL-connector 6.2.2

But I didnt't test anything but simple save and read queries.

Answer (score 0):

from the looks of the code not everything seems to be full hilt 3.5 so i would cast an opinion that it will be just fine, i have been using 3.0.0.3 and resharper comes up with tones of comments about how it can be changed and upgraded.

but it takes less than 5 mins or so to test, so i would go ahead if i was you, you dont really have much to loose other than 5-10 mins.

hope this helps